# Need guidance trying to make a memory game in Android Studio. How and where can I command the cards?

Tags: java, android, database, button, memory

I'm a beginner at programming including in android studio, and was wondering if anyone's willing to help. I was able to figure out how to flip the cards, but have a couple of problems:

**1-** how can I randomize each back image, if I was going to retrieve it from a database?

**2-** How and where can I put the command that tells the cards to stay open if 2 cards are the same and to flip back if they aren't?
 here is my code:

```
package com.example.lab.memorygame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView pic1;
    ImageView pic2;
    ImageView pic3;
    ImageView pic4;

    public class Card{
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public Button button;

        public Card(Button button, int x,int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y=y;
            this.button=button;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get references to the imageView objects
        pic1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgUpperLeft);
        pic2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        pic3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        pic4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

        // Setting the initial image
        pic1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_waterfall);
        pic2.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_waterfall);
        pic3.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_waterfall);
        pic4.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_waterfall);

        pic1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pic2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pic3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pic4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }

    public void showUpperLeftImage(View v){
        pic1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_smlee);
    }
    public void showUpperRightImage(View v){
        pic2.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_smlee);
    }
    public void showLowerLeftImage(View v){

        pic3.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_smlee);
    }
    public void showLowerRightImage(View v){
        pic4.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_smlee);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

If you need more info please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Create animation using xml file card_flip_left_in.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Before rotating, immediately set the alpha to 0. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="0" />

    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="-180"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 1. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
        android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

card_flip_left_out.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="180"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 0. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
        android:duration="1" />
</set>



private void flipCard() {
    if (mShowingBack) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        return;
    }

    // Flip to the back.

    mShowingBack = true;

    // Create and commit a new fragment transaction that adds the fragment for
    // the back of the card, uses custom animations, and is part of the fragment
    // manager's back stack.

    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()

            // Replace the default fragment animations with animator resources
            // representing rotations when switching to the back of the card, as
            // well as animator resources representing rotations when flipping
            // back to the front (e.g. when the system Back button is pressed).
            .setCustomAnimations(
                    R.animator.card_flip_right_in,
                    R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                    R.animator.card_flip_left_in,
                    R.animator.card_flip_left_out)

            // Replace any fragments currently in the container view with a
            // fragment representing the next page (indicated by the
            // just-incremented currentPage variable).
            .replace(R.id.container, new CardBackFragment())

            // Add this transaction to the back stack, allowing users to press
            // Back to get to the front of the card.
            .addToBackStack(null)

            // Commit the transaction.
            .commit();
}
```

card_flip_right_in.xml
card_flip_right_out.xml get from below link.
You can get reference from http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html
I think it is help u.

Comment: Thanks to remind me and i will keep in mind for future answers.